# Reading tab delimited csv into numpy array with different data types

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I have a tab delimited csv dataset as following:

```
1       2       3       4       5       6       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
3       1       2       6       4       5       [2, 0, 1, 5, 3, 4]
7       8       9       10      11      6       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
10      11      9       8       7       6       [3, 4, 2, 1, 0, 5]
12      13      4       14      15      6       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
13      4       14      12      15      6       [1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5]
16      17      18      19      20      6       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
6       18      20      17      16      19      [5, 2, 4, 1, 0, 3]
7       21      22      23      24      6       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
23      6       21      7       22      24      [3, 5, 1, 0, 2, 4]
25      7       21      22      23      6       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
6       21      7       22      25      23      [5, 2, 1, 3, 0, 4]
16      26      3       27      28      6       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
26      6       27      3       28      16      [1, 5, 3, 2, 4, 0]
7       29      24      30      31      6       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
30      24      6       7       29      31      [3, 2, 5, 0, 1, 4]
32      33      13      34      35      36      [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
34      32      36      35      13      33      [3, 0, 5, 4, 2, 1]
7       37      38      39      40      6       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
39      38      40      6       37      7       [3, 2, 4, 5, 1, 0]
7       41      42      43      44      6       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
41      6       44      43      42      7       [1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 0]
7       45      46      47      48      6       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
6       47      45      7       46      48      [5, 3, 1, 0, 2, 4]
49      2       50      51      52      6       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

When I want to import such csv file into a numpy array as following;

```
dataset = numpy.loadtxt('dataset/demo_dataset.csv', delimiter='\t', dtype='str')
```

I obtain a numpy array with `(25,)` shape.

I want to import this csv file into two numpy arrays, called X and Y.

X will include the first 6 columns, and Y will include last column as list values, not str.

How can I manage it?

Comment: It's easy enough to load the 6 columns as integers, and the last column as string.  `dtype=None` should do it, or a more eleborate custom dtype.  But `[]` strings require special handling, either before `genfromtxt` or after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to achieve this only via a custom method:

```
import numpy

with open('dataset/demo_dataset.csv', 'r') as fin:
    lines = fin.readlines()
    # remove '\n' characters
    clean_lines = [l.strip('\n') for l in lines]
    # split on tab so that we get lists from strings
    A = [cl.split('\t') for cl in clean_lines]
    # get lists of ints instead of lists of strings
    X = [map(int, row[0:6]) for row in A]
    # last column in Y
    Y = [row[6] for row in A]

    # convert string to int values
    for i in xrange(len(Y)):
        Y[i] = map(int, Y[i].strip('[]').split(','))
```

Answer (score 2):

Some options using `genfromtxt`:

```
In [1047]: txt=b"""7\t8\t9\t10\t11\t6\t [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"""
In [1048]: txt=[txt,txt,txt]
In [1049]: txt
Out[1049]: 
[b'7\t8\t9\t10\t11\t6\t [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]',
 b'7\t8\t9\t10\t11\t6\t [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]',
 b'7\t8\t9\t10\t11\t6\t [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]']
```

load as the default floats - the last column is `nan`:

```
In [1050]: np.genfromtxt(txt,delimiter='\t')
Out[1050]: 
array([[  7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  11.,   6.,  nan],
       [  7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  11.,   6.,  nan],
       [  7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  11.,   6.,  nan]])
```

As strings

```
In [1051]: np.genfromtxt(txt,delimiter='\t',dtype='str')
Out[1051]: 
array([['7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '6', ' [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'],
       ['7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '6', ' [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'],
       ['7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '6', ' [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]']], 
      dtype='<U19')
```

Letting it decide the best fit - result is a structured array, with int fields and one string field.

```
In [1052]: np.genfromtxt(txt,delimiter='\t',dtype=None)
Out[1052]: 
array([(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 6, b' [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'),
       (7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 6, b' [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'),
       (7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 6, b' [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4'), ('f4', '<i4'), ('f5', '<i4'), ('f6', 'S19')])
In [1053]: _['f6']
Out[1053]: 
array([b' [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]', b' [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]',
       b' [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'], 
      dtype='|S19')
```

Refine the dtype - one field has 6 columns, the other string:

```
In [1055]: np.genfromtxt(txt,delimiter='\t',dtype='6int,S20')
Out[1055]: 
array([([7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 6], b' [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'),
       ([7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 6], b' [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'),
       ([7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 6], b' [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]')], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4', (6,)), ('f1', 'S20')])
```

The first field is your desired `X`; the strings in the last field need further processing (as per your other question):

```
In [1060]: _['f0']
Out[1060]: 
array([[ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  6]])
In [1061]: __['f1']
Out[1061]: 
array([b' [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]', b' [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]',
       b' [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'],
```

This last field can be converted as `@chefarov` does with the `Y` variable.

Come to think of, I could process that string field with another call to `genfromtxt`.  I still need to remove the `[]`.

```
In [1101]: data=np.genfromtxt(txt,delimiter='\t',dtype='6int,S20')
In [1102]: data['f1']
Out[1102]: 
array([b'[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]', b'[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]', b'[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'], 
      dtype='|S20')
In [1103]: np.genfromtxt([l.strip(b'[]') for l in data['f1']],delimiter=',',dtype=int)
Out[1103]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

I've recommended, in other cases, preprocessing the lines to remove quotes, brackets and problem delimiters.  `genfromtxt` accepts input from anything that feeds it lines.  But in this case, the required processing is most of what `@chefarov` proposes - minus the `int` conversions.

`genfromtxt` also accepts converters, but I found in other questions that a converter can't change one field into multiple ones.

Also `genfromtxt` iterates on the file lines, and decodes each and collects the values in a list.  So it doesn't have any speed advantage for a custom reader.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `pandas`, there's an (arguably) simpler approach to read the data in. First, a `pandas.DataFrame` instance can be constructed, and we can apply a custom function to its last column to convert string elements to `np.ndarray` types:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_table('dataset/demo_dataset.csv', delimiter='\t', names='abcdefg')
convert = lambda a: np.fromstring(a[1:-1], count = a.count(',') + 1, sep = ', ', dtype=int)
df.g = df.g.apply(convert)
```

Once a mixed dataframe is constructed, `X` and `Y` can be extracted as arrays in a simple fashion:

```
X = df.values[:, :-1].astype(int)
Y = np.vstack(df.values[:, -1])
```